# How do I update the y axis of the chart using D3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**How do I update the y axis of a D3 js chart?**

In my example, the x axis contains labels (countries) and the y axis contains it's corresponding value (population).

The y axis domain is [0, maxValue] and whenever I update the values, if there is a new max value, I have to extend the axis domain to [0, newMaxValue].

I just can't seem to figure it out from all the examples I've found on the internet.

This is the function which creates the chart:

```
function drawBarChart(divChartId, chartDimensions) {
    var margin = chartDimensions["margin"];
    var width = chartDimensions["width"];
    var height = chartDimensions["height"];

    // append the svg object
    var svg = d3.select(divChartId)
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    data = [
        { Country: "abc", Value: 10 },
        { Country: "ghewt", Value: 24 },
        { Country: "eerrtt", Value: 5 },
        { Country: "sa", Value: 16 },
        { Country: "xdff", Value: 9 },
    ];

    // X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.Country; }))
        .padding(0.2);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
        .style("text-anchor", "end");

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function (d) { return d.Value; }))])
        .range([height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Generate random color
    var colorObject = generateRandomColorObject();

    // Bars
    svg.selectAll("mybar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.Country); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(0); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(0); })
        .attr("fill", colorObject.color)
        .style("stroke", colorObject.border)
        .style("stroke-width", 1);

    // Animation
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .transition()
        .duration(1200)
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.Value); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.Value); })
        .delay(function (d, i) { return (i * 100) })

    
};
```

This is the update function which I'm working on

```
function update(chartDimensions) {
    var svg = d3.select("#divChart1");

    var margin = chartDimensions["margin"];
    var width = chartDimensions["width"];
    var height = chartDimensions["height"];

    data = [
        { Country: "abc", Value: 10 },
        { Country: "ghewt", Value: 50 },
        { Country: "eerrtt", Value: 5 },
        { Country: "sa", Value: 16 },
        { Country: "xdff", Value: 9 },
    ];

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function (d) { return d.Value; }))])
        .range([height, 0]);

    svg.select("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Say your new data is in data. We can use [`d3.extent()`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-extent) to compute the new data's min and max. We pass to it a function which tells what property to compute the min and max on, in this case the `value` property.

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(d => d.value))
    .range([height, 0]);
```